# Movie sound/music editing : better solution than VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

Third question of my concern about producing high quality short movies. The question is quite simple :

**Is audio as weak as video in the VSE ? Is there another way of managing sound than the VSE ?**

It would be convenient to use the VSE for audio, as it is (at least for me) intuitive and easy to work with. I know I could do the same work with like Audacity, but it seems really painful from my point of view. The only missing feature is a visualization of audio volume, but I'm guessing some add-ons exist for that.

Comment: The VSE is designed to string animation clips together, so you are expected to bring your own mixed audio to the project. You can import and move pieces of audio around the timeline, then export them to a DAW application. There is only rudimentary volume control and no visualisation available in Blender. Nor will there be AFAIK

Comment: *Audio is weaker than Video in the VSE*. Many high quality shorts with work with layout sounds throughout the editing process and then reconstruct the audio properly in a daw after picture lock.

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on for exporting the audio to Ardour: http://blendervelvets.org/en/blue-velvet/
And if you export the video as one file, it can be added to Ardour too, so you'll be editing the audio in a DAW while watching the video in sync. However, Ardour is only free, if you know how to build it yourself, or you'll have to pay "something".

Alternatively, there is an EDL export add-on(text-file), which will allow you to export info for one video track and four audio tracks, but ex. Davinci Resolve will not import audio from EDL files - in D.R. EDL files are only used for conforming video edits. https://github.com/tin2tin/ExportEDL

Third option add-on-wise is to use this add-on to roundtrip single audio clips in ex. Audacity: https://github.com/Joeboy/blender-addons/blob/master/open_strip_source.py This one does not work right away on Win 8, because you'll have to manually add the full path for audacity.exe. I might add some more functionality to this add-on, to make it more user-friendly.

Jack could be used on Linux to control an external volume monitor: https://audaspace.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/jack-transport/

Last option is to export each channel as a stem audio file(just one file pr. track with beep for sync) and import those in a DAW and make cuts where needed.